# ui-router version 0.2.* has gone from npm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have `"ui-router": "^0.2.15"` line in my `package.json` and recently `npm i` has become broken with the `npm ERR! No compatible version found: ui-router@^0.2.15` error. As far as I understood all versions lower than `[ '1.0.0-alpha0' ]` were removed from npm registry. Is it an expected behaviour? Were there any deprecation notifications?

Comment: Do you have no possibility to upgrade to upper/current version?

Comment: `npm install angular-ui-router@0.2.15` works for me still

Comment: @KirillSlatin, thanks. It looks like I was confused by these two - [angular-ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-router) and [ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-router). To be honest I'm still confused. Why there're two repos for the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two packages on npmjs, ui-router and angular-ui-router.

They are both referencing same repository on github (http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and are managed by the same person: Christopher Thielen. If you take a look at the package description of [angular-ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-router) and [ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-router) you can notice that latest versions are different 0.2.18 vs 1.0.0-alpha0 (as of the moment of this post). I suppose Christopher did this on purpose to maintain legacy version and 1.*